# Post Request to Spring Entity with a Foreign key

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables **employee** and **reimbursement** with a OneToMany relation.
Passing a post request to reimbursement gives me the error `"Column 'emp_id' cannot be null`" *(emp_id is the foreign key)*

My Entities are:
**Employee:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private long empId;
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "manager", nullable = false)
    @Value("false")
    private boolean manager;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Reimbursement> reimbursements = new HashSet<>();

    public long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(long empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    // (...) other getters and setters

    public Set<Reimbursement> getReimbursements() {
        return reimbursements;
    }

    public void setReimbursements(Set<Reimbursement> reimbursements) {
        this.reimbursements = reimbursements;
    }
}
```

**Reimbursement:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "reimbursements"
)
public class Reimbursement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private double amount;
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    @Value("false")
    private boolean status; //whether the expense has been reimbursed

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Employee employee;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    //(...) other getters and setters

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }

}
```

**Post Controller:**

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Reimbursement> createReimbursement(@RequestBody Reimbursement reimbursement) {
        var data = reimbursementService.createReimbursement(reimbursement);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

**Service:**

```
    @Override
    public Reimbursement createReimbursement(Reimbursement reimbursement) {
        return reimbursementRepository.save(reimbursement);
    }
```

I tried passing this JSON as a POST request (employee with id 1 already exists in the employee table)

```
{
  "employee": {
    "emp_id": "1"
  },
  "description": "example",
  "amount": "123",
  "status": "false"
}
```

I am new to Spring Boot. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Reimbursement> createReimbursement(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
      
    var data = reimbursementService.createReimbursement(employee);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(data, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@Override
public Employee createReimbursement(Employee employee) {
    Set<Reimbursement> list = employee.getReimbursements();
    reimbursementRepository.save(employee);
    Iterator<Reimbursement> reimbursement= list.iterator();
    while(reimbursement.hasNext()) {
        reimbursement.setEmpeloyee(employee);
        reimbursementRepository.save(reimbursement);
    }
    return employee;
}
```

In post method you should give base Entity Using base entity you will get all relational entity values .First you should save base entity later you set employee object Reimbursement for every object later you will save it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my problem with the help of your answer. For anyone with the same problem, what I did was pass the the id outside of the JSON separately as a PathVariable or RequestParam, and in the create method of the service, add two lines before saving the reimbursement to the repository: get employee by id, set employee to reimbursement. No need of extracting the set or looping

Comment: You give that path in your UI because of while editing time you need that employee id because you have one many you should pathvarible and request PARAM used for get by employee Id go to this link you will get  ---- >  
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-one-to-many-mapping-in-spring-boot/